# Closing file child descriptors after killing parent?

Tags: c, linux, posix

How can I close my child file descriptors when killing the parent process?

I've created a program that does the following:

1. Fork 2 child processes.
2. Process 1 is a reader. It reads from STDIN_FILENO and writes to STDOUT_FILENO with scanf/printf. But I use dup2 to redirect to a named pipe (let's call it npipe).
3. Process 2 is a writer. I redirect STDIN_FILENO to npipe so that I can use scanf from that pipe. I redirect STDOUT_FILENO to another file called "output_file" so that I can use printf to write.

Reading / Writing is done in a while(1) loop;

```
while(1){
scanf("%s",word);
printf("%s",word);
}
```

If I use CTRL+C (send SIGTERM signal to the parent), any data that was written in "output_file" is lost. Nothing is inside there. I think it's because I kill the processes while the files are opened?

I used a word that stops both child processes when read; in this case, I do have everything in my "output_file".

How can I close the files when using SIGTERM? / Can I somehow force my process to write into "output_file" so that no data is lost when suddenly closing?

I tried closing and opening the file after each writing. Still losing all the written data? Is this because of the redirect?

```
void read_from_pipe(void)
{
    char command[100];
    int new_fd = open(pipe_name,O_RDONLY,0644);
    int output_file = open("new_file",O_CREAT|O_WRONLY|O_APPEND,0644);

    dup2(new_fd,0);
    dup2(output_file,1);
    while(1)
    {   
        scanf("%s",command);
        if(strcmp(command,"stop")==0)
        {
            close(output_file);
            close(new_fd);
            exit(0);
        }
        else
        printf("%s ",command); 
        close(output_file);
        output_file = open("new_file",O_CREAT|O_WRONLY|O_APPEND,0644);
    }    
}
```

Managed to attach correct signal handlers, yet data is still not written even though I close my files! Why is that?

Comment: You need to install a signal handler that will ensure your file is closed upon exit.

Comment: Tried to do it but it seems that the children are oblivious to it. Plus i do not know how to make a different handler for both of the children for the same signal.

Comment: If you fork your process after installing the signal handlers, your child processes will have the signal handler. You can then install another handler in your parent that will propagate the signal to children. Also, you can open your file with FSYNC flag.

Comment: Yeah,makes sense! That would be a natural solution;
Okay but i tried the next thing and something was wrong again...
I close the file after each writing yet data still isn't written in the file ..

Comment: "_father_"? why not use the standard "_parent_"?

Comment: Ah,that's because of my first language. We usually call them that way. Did not even notice! I' ll change it now.

Comment: Ctrl-C sends SIGINT, not SIGTERM.

Comment: Yes, that works! Now my signals work perfectly! The problem is that data is still not written even though i close my files! :(

Comment: I don't see a [mcve] in your post.

Comment: An XY problem?  Your problem seems to be not getting stuff written to the file, which is likely due to buffering and has nothing to do with signals or closing (or not) file descriptors.

Comment: yes, the problem it seems to be more buffer related. The problem is though that fflush doesn't work; 
I managed to make it work by writing setbuf(stdout,0); But this had to be written in the parent process not in the child. I don't understand why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You problem is (likely) not to do with closing the file descriptors, it's with flushing the FILE pointers.  Note that FILE pointers and file descriptors are two different things.

You call `printf`, which does NOT write to STDOUT_FILENO (a file descriptor), it writes to stdout (a FILE pointer), which generally just buffers the data until it has a reason to write it to the underlying file descriptor (STDOUT_FILENO).

So you need to ensure your data that you write to stdout is actually written to STDOUT_FILENO.  The easiest way to do that is to stick an `fflush(stdout);` after the printf call to manually flush it, giving you fine-grained control over when stuff is written.  Alternately, you can call `setbuf(stdout, 0);` to make stdout unbuffered, so every write will be flushed immediately.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! It sounds like this could be my problem.
LATER EDIT:
Well, I tried using  fflush(stdout); and setbuf(stdout,0); But somehow it strangely doesn't force the writing of data .

Comment: He could also open the file with `O_FSYNC`, which would ensure that the data is written to disk before any `write()` call return.

Comment: @sturcotte06 That only affects the file descritpor and the writes, not the FILE pointer and its buffering, so is likely irrelevant to the OP's actual problem.

Comment: Yeah you're right, I thought he was using POSIX interface. But stdin and stdout are streams. My bad ;)

Comment: Hi, it seems that  setbuf(stdout, 0);  works but only if it was used in the parent process. I don't understand why fflush won't work after printf / why  setbuf in child won't work.

Comment: As the reason why the non-working part of my program is not related strong enough to my question i decided to close this one.